# "Could not broadcast input array" in system of stiff odes inside a loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, scipy, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a system of stiff odes which describes a catalytic heterogeneous reaction. I want to solve this equations for different temperatures, so I'm using a for loop.

```
import scipy as sc
from scipy.integrate import odeint, solve_ivp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
T=np.array([250,300,350,400,450,500])
for y in T:
    y=T
    def f(t,x,T=y,tfirst=True):
        FA,FB,FC,FD,FE,FF=x
        e=2.711828
        R=8.314
        Tm=723.15
        A1=5.5
        A2=0.686
        A3=1.58
        A4=2.6
        A5=0.787
        E1=90500
        E2=165000
        E3=150000
        E4=139000
        E5=132000
        SB=-215
        HB=-45600
        SD=-42
        HD=-128000
        DH1=-105000
        DH2=-1428000
        DH3=-862000
        DH4=-1323000
        DH5=-757000
        k1=e**(A1-(E1/R)*((1/T)-(1/Tm)))
        k2=e**(A2-(E2/R)*((1/T)-(1/Tm)))
        k3=e**(A3-(E3/R)*((1/T)-(1/Tm)))
        k4=e**(A4-(E4/R)*((1/T)-(1/Tm)))
        k5=e**(A5-(E5/R)*((1/T)-(1/Tm)))
        KB=6.54e-12
        KD=1.19
        m2=0.922
        m3=0.906
        m4=1.23
        m5=0.905
        Patm=0.8*101325
        FT=178.47
        PA=(FA/FT)*Patm
        PB=(FB/FT)*Patm
        PC=(FC/FT)*Patm
        PD=(FD/FT)*Patm
        PE=(FE/FT)*Patm
        PF=(FF/FT)*Patm
        Tast=1/(1+((KB*PB)**0.5)+(KD*PD))
        TB=((KB*PB)**0.5)*Tast
        TD=KD*PD*Tast
        r1=(k1/1000)*TB*PA #mol
        r2=(k2/1000)*(TB**m2)*PA
        r3=(k3/1000)*(TB**m3)*PA
        r4=(k4/1000)*(TB**m4)*PC
        r5=(k5/1000)*(TB**m5)*PC
        rA=-r1-r2-r3
        rB=-r1-7*r2-5*r3-6*r4-4*r5
        rC=r1-r4-r5
        rD=r1+3*r2+3*r3+2*r4+2*r5
        rE=2*r2+2*r4
        rF=2*r3+2*r5
        FAdot=rA
        FBdot=rB
        FCdot=rC
        FDdot=rD
        FEdot=rE
        FFdot=rF
        return [FAdot,FBdot,FCdot,FDdot,FEdot,FFdot]
x0=(5,5,0,0,0,0)
t0=0
t1=40
soln=solve_ivp(f,(t0,t1),x0,method="Radau",args=(T,))
print(soln.y)
```

I get the following error:

```
c:\Users\Axel Flores\Documents\Escuela\Proyectos\Python\import scipy as sc.py:51: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  Tast=1/(1+((KB*PB)**0.5)+(KD*PD))
c:\Users\Axel Flores\Documents\Escuela\Proyectos\Python\import scipy as sc.py:52: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  TB=((KB*PB)**0.5)*Tast
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Axel Flores\Documents\Escuela\Proyectos\Python\import scipy as sc.py", line 75, in <module>
    soln=solve_ivp(f,(t0,t1),x0,method="Radau",args=(T,))
  File "C:\Users\Axel Flores\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\ivp.py", line 546, in solve_ivp
    solver = method(fun, t0, y0, tf, vectorized=vectorized, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Axel Flores\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\radau.py", line 310, in __init__
    self.jac, self.J = self._validate_jac(jac, jac_sparsity)
  File "C:\Users\Axel Flores\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\radau.py", line 356, in _validate_jac   
    J = jac_wrapped(t0, y0, self.f)
  File "C:\Users\Axel Flores\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\radau.py", line 352, in jac_wrapped     
    J, self.jac_factor = num_jac(self.fun_vectorized, t, y, f,
  File "C:\Users\Axel Flores\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\common.py", line 316, in num_jac        
    return _dense_num_jac(fun, t, y, f, h, factor, y_scale)
  File "C:\Users\Axel Flores\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\common.py", line 326, in _dense_num_jac 
    f_new = fun(t, y[:, None] + h_vecs)
  File "C:\Users\Axel Flores\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\base.py", line 133, in fun_vectorized   
    f[:, i] = self._fun(t, yi)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (6,6) into shape (6,)
PS C:\Users\Axel Flores>
```

Anyone could help?

I believe the error is related to the for loop. But everything that I've tried hasn't worked.

Comment: full error message.  Don't make us guess where

Comment: Do a test calc. e.g. `f(t0, x0, T)`

Comment: Within `f` test the `T`.  Is it the whole `T` array or one element of it?

Comment: I already edited the post in order to show the full error.

Answer (score 0):

Take a hard look on the effect of

```
for y in T:
    y=T
    def f(t,x,T=y,tfirst=True):
```

and how that introduces the extra dimension of size 6.